# How do I check if a channel exists on YouTube?

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

If I make a `curl` request for this URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC_x5XG1OVP6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&key=...`

I'll get the output as:

```
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
      "etag": "J801W-IQ15sDpy3GjDfjlUgoVxA",
      "pageInfo": {
        "resultsPerPage": 0
      }
    }
```

Does this mean that the YouTube channel doesn't exist?
I don't get any error; how to find whether this is a valid channel or not?

Likewise, I want the list of videos of a given channel. If I make a `curl` request using this URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCIJIhBwx4XjNUtQGZTGSVnA&maxResults=20&order=date&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

I'll get the output as:

```
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
      "etag": "q5r0QewUnrg2C7BdwuxbJxb9b8c",
      "regionCode": "IN",
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 20
      },
      "items": []
    }
```

This is a valid channel ID, but I get an empty result, not an error; how to know the search is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

### Question no. 1

For what concerns your first question:

> Given a channel ID -- `$CHANNEL_ID` --, test whether the respective channel exists or not.

I would recommend invoking `curl` on the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&fields=items/id&id=$CHANNEL_ID&key=$APP_KEY`

Note that invoking the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint through the URL above -- which contains the parameters `part=id` and `fields=items/id` -- will return *only* the channel's ID.

Although not documented explicitly, tests show that you'll get back from the endpoint the ID you passed on to it, *if and only if* that channel does actually exist.

For example, in case of your channel ID above -- `UC_x5XG1OVP6uZZ5FSM9Ttw` --, the API response is trivially empty:

```
{}
```

becase this channel does not exist (only have to click on this [link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_x5XG1OVP6uZZ5FSM9Ttw) to see that yourself).

On the other hand, in case of NBCNews' channel -- `UCeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg` -- the response is:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "UCeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg"
    }
  ]
}
```

showing that indeed this channel is live and kicking.

### Question no. 2

For what concerns the second question of your post:

> Given a channel by its ID `$CHANNEL_ID`, do list the videos of that channel.

I recommend you to consult [the answer I gave recently to this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811627/8327971).

In terms of `curl`, you'll have to invoke the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&fields=items/contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads&id=$CHANNEL_ID&key=$APP_KEY`

for to obtain that channel's uploads playlist ID. For example, in the case of NBCNews' channel, the API response is:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "contentDetails": {
        "relatedPlaylists": {
          "uploads": "UUeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then take out that ID from the JSON response as `$PLAYLIST_ID` and invoke `curl` on the following URL *repeatedly*, [implementing pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination):

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&maxResults=50&playlistId=$PLAYLIST_ID&key=$APP_KEY`.

In case of NBCNews' uploads playlist, *the output of the first page* would look like:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "5DW9uT73DWmJtDoJ-rSw3AqHKpc",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "_X3LvLIRvEBM3RetizOGtB03ja0",
      "id": "VVVlWTBiYm50V3p6VklhajJ6M1FpZ1hnLjE5NjU4N0NGQkY5M0M3MjI=",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-09-12T06:11:59Z",
        "channelId": "UCeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg",
        "title": "Watch NBC News NOW Live - September 11",
        "description": "NBC News NOW is live, reporting breaking news and ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "NBC News",
        "playlistId": "UUeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg",
        "position": 0,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "yXO2hQXC5Dw"
        }
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "videoId": "yXO2hQXC5Dw",
        "videoPublishedAt": "2020-09-12T06:11:59Z"
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "PGyhZonOjiRzqHu7DKDPk6gcMTo",
      "id": "VVVlWTBiYm50V3p6VklhajJ6M1FpZ1hnLjY2RTJFNDA4MDA0NDREQTU=",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-09-12T02:48:48Z",
        "channelId": "UCeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg",
        "title": "Gaza Sees Spike In Coronavirus Cases, Severe Shortage Of Supplies | NBC News NOW",
        "description": "NBC News’ Kelly Cobiella reports on the surge in Gaza ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "NBC News",
        "playlistId": "UUeY0bbntWzzVIaj2z3QigXg",
        "position": 1,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "I0lHV0ZVPAs"
        }
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "videoId": "I0lHV0ZVPAs",
        "videoPublishedAt": "2020-09-12T02:48:48Z"
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public"
      }
    },
    ...
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 20000,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  }
}
```

Do notice the property `nextPageToken` within the JSON response text above; the value of this property -- `CAUQAA` -- would have to be passed to the second invocation of the endpoint as the parameter `pageToken=CAUQAA` added to the initial URL above.

For to obtain the `n`-th page, you'll extract the value of `nextPageToken` from the `n-1`-th page, for to pass that value to the the `n`-th URL as `pageToken=...`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no request in the API that will tell you 100% if a channel exits or not.

Even doing a do a video search for the channel wont help you as.  If it exists then it would return the videos for that channel, if not then you get back 0 videos.

## request

```
curl \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCMPpVtxOI8RtfurfvCcxgyA&order=date&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \  
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--compressed
```

## response

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "oaf4zpPSG6Ho_cSxZedNhuVhjkw",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "DK",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1721,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
```

## no channel

In the event no channel exists the above code will return total results of 0

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "opQHhlM-mBA_i0h80B_gmHdKgCE",
  "regionCode": "DK",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": []
}
```

## Another option

Another option would be to not use the API at all.  Just make a call to against YouTube itself.

If you load this page it loads the actual channel https://www.youtube.com/c/NBCNews  However if you try to load https://www.youtube.com/c/lafjdajdskfadkfj it redirects you to https://www.youtube.com/error?src=404  i would think that would be something simple to detect.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for answering. i want the search to be order by **Date**. If the videos does not exit for that channel it will return empty not error. how to know this is valid search or not.

Comment: I have changed my anwser to include an order by **Date**, as well as the fact that the response for a channel that does not exist will return 0 results not an error.   Ordering by date is a valid option.

Comment: There are channels which have no uploads, so this tactic will not work.

Comment: Did you check my other option?