# YouTube Private/Unlisted Videos By Channel ID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the list of the videos for a specific channel by specifying the channel ID. I used the search but it worked only for public videos. I need to get this list (especially of unlisted videos) either by HTTP requests, or the SDK (NuGet package in C#) preferably. Please note that these unlisted videos may not be in a playlist, so I need a generic solution solely based on channel ID if it exists. Also, I am authenticating as a user who owns/posted those unlisted videos, if that'll make any difference.

Comment: It is private for a reason, unless its your channel then you should be able to list all with proper authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that without proper authorization, one *cannot list* non-public video meta-data.

For *to list* a given channel's video meta-data, you may employ the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint queried with the parameter [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) set to the ID of that channel's uploads playlist.

This latter ID may very easily be obtained by invoking the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint queried with the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) set to your channel's ID or, otherwise, by passing on the parameter [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) as `mine=true`.

The uploads playlist ID is then to be found within the endpoint's JSON response as value of the property [`items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads). Note that for a given channel, you need to obtain the uploads playlist ID only once, then use it as many times as you wish.

Usually, a channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

Comment: This is another answer that does not answer the question - but kinda suggests that it does. "Please note that without proper authorization, one cannot list non-public video meta-data." This implies that with proper authorization you could list private or unlisted videos via documented google APIs. However while testing with the official google APIs explorer using either their OAuth 2.0 implementation with the YouTube account owner or the API key - in both cases cannot retrieve unlisted or private videos via publicly documented APIs. It only returns public videos.

Comment: @BenSwayne: With proper authorization -- i.e. **being in the possession of *a valid access token*** --, one is able to access private data. If that wouldn't be the case then Google's issue tracker site would explode from user complains. On the other hand, don't trust much Google's API Explorer. E.g. [write your own (simple) Python script](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/my_uploads.py) to see that the API works as expected. And do *note that you're in front of a non-trivial API*; therefore, expect that things may well force you to *read the official docs.*

Comment: Thanks @stvar. The confusion appears to be what constitutes a "valid" access token for private/unlisted videos. Some tokens "work" but only return the public items. Upon further research it seems that if you have a YouTube "Brand Account", you must have an OAuth token for the brand account, not just a user account with permissions for that brand account. When I am going through the OAuth consent screen for google login it will ask me to pick the "email account" or "brand account", I must pick the brand account in order to list private or unlisted items. Will test more.