# YouTube Data API v3: sort videos by most popular

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When you view videos on YouTube there is an option to sort by date or most popular:

[image]

How does YouTube sort this? Does it use statistics from [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)?

Answer (score 1):

You better ask this question to Google itself (through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/)).

We -- non-Googlers -- can only guess: it's to be expected that the YouTube Data API and the YouTube's website have behind them the very same back-end.

But keep in mind that YouTube Data API is (by design) made such that to *not replicate all* the features/functionalities of `https://www.youtube.com`.

Also, in this context is worth mentioning that, according to [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies), one is not allowed to (quote from section [I. Additional Prohibitions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#i.-additional-prohibitions), point 1):

> mimic or replicate YouTube's core user experiences by recreating features or process flows unless they add significant independent value or functionality that improves users' interactions with YouTube.

---

Unfortunately, there's no API endpoint that will return the list of uploaded videos of a channel, ordering the items returned by popularity (i.e. by [`viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount)).

But there's a well-known way to [list a channel's uploaded videos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811627/8327971) -- then you may well sort the items obtained the way you need.

Comment: Furthermore, @Toniq, if you'll be more precise with your question (w.r.t. what API endpoint you're referring when you want to *sort videos by most popular*), I'll update my answer above accordingly. The screenshot above is to be seen on (almost) every channel's *Videos* tab: in other words, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was just wondering was there an api endpoint to achieve this.