# Next Page Token is not functional and display only maximum (50) results

Tags: java, android-studio, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch all videos of a channel using youtube data api, but my code is giving error and doesn't respond to PAGE token

```
displayVideos();

    }


    private void displayVideos ()
    {
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {



            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("nextPageToken"));
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (jsonObject1.has("id")){
                            JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                            if (jsonVideoId.has("kind")){
                                if(jsonVideoId.getString("kind").equals("youtube#video")){
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectDefault=jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                                    String video_id=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                                    VideoDetails vd=new VideoDetails();

                                    vd.setVideoId(video_id);
                                    vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                                    vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                                    vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                                    videoDetailsoArrayList.add(vd);

                                }
                                //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

the url I am trying to parse is

```
    String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVMWWQ985A_-SESZUy_SsVQ&maxResults=50&pageToken="+nextPageToken+"&order=date&pageToken=CAUQAA&key=API_KEY";
```

I have been searchingb to apply nextpage token or page token in android studio but couldnt get specific tutorial. there are many examples but being naive in android studio I cant implement it into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your URL does contain two instances of the parameter `pageToken`:

`"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVMWWQ985A_-SESZUy_SsVQ&maxResults=50&pageToken="+nextPageToken+"&order=date&pageToken=CAUQAA&key=API_KEY"`.

It should have only one for that to work OK; to be more precise, your URL should contain only this instance: `pageToken="+nextPageToken+"`.

---

On the other hand, your code above does not show the loop implementing pagination. That is that you haven't shown the piece of code where you actually assign a valid value to the  variable `nextPageToken`.

Therefore I cannot tell if your program will work or not.

---

The pagination loop would look like this:

```
// initially no pageToken
nextPageToken = null;
// URL as above, without the parameter pageToken
url = ...

do {
  invoke the API on the URL: url + (nextPageToken != null ? "&pageToken=" + nextPageToken : "")
  nextPageToken = jsonObject.get("nextPageToken");
} while (nextPageToken != null)
```

Comment: can you please guide me about looping in this code?

Comment: Just read the section entitled *Question no. 2* of [this answer I gave recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859745/8327971). Specifically the last two paragraphs. Then come back posting new comments down below.

Comment: ```  String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVMWWQ985A_-SESZUy_SsVQ&maxResults=50&order=date&pageToken="+nextPageToken+"key=API_KEY"; ``` the url should look like this but how to apply the loop for next page token? how to edit java json code for looping?

Comment: The 1st URL does not have `pageToken=...`, but the JSON response contains `nextPageToken` (which you already print it out on the console by `System.out.println(jsonObject.get("nextPageToken"));`

Comment: Thus the 2nd URL would have `pageToken=" + nextPageToken + "`, where `nextPageToken` was previously assigned as `nextPageToken = jsonObject.get("nextPageToken");`

Comment: And so on, the `n`-th URL would have `pageToken=" + nextPageToken + "` where `nextPageToken` was previously assigned from the value within the `n-1`-th page.

Comment: Can you see the loop here? (This is a plain induction loop.)

Comment: yes I got the logic but Iam getting confused in exact coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221471/discussion-between-summyia-haris-and-stvar).