# Check if youtube channel ID is valid

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, websub

I just made my pubsubhubbub wrapper and now I need to let users subscribe to a channel notifications. The simpler solution is to just check if the channel ID they provide is valid. I could fetch the yt site but dont want to get my ip rate limited or banned. So I guess using the API but I find the docs very confusing and can't find the correct endpoint.

Then the better solution would be to let the users provide channel name and it would give them an option to select from lets say top 5 results. But my question this time is what is the rate limit? I remember that there was a credit system but I can't find anywhere what is the cost and how it refreshes.

Thank you for all the support

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [How do I check if a channel exists on YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859745/8327971)

Comment: @stvar thanks and what about the credit cost of channel search? I still cant find that anywhere :( Thanks

Comment: That's not a channel search, i.e. is not invoking the rather expensive [`Search.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint (100 units of quota cost per call); but is invoking the inexpensive [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, which, according to the spec page I just mentioned, has a quota cost of 1 unit.